Unable to Restore NuGet Packages in Docker Build: Remote Name Could Not Be Resolved
I'm trying to build a Docker image for my .NET application using the following command:
docker build --pull -t demo .
During the build process, I encounter the following error when the nuget restore command is executed:
arduinoCopy codeStep 6/12 : RUN nuget restore
---> Running in 2cd6dfb85d98
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '17.11.2.32701' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin'.
Restoring NuGet package Antlr.3.5.0.2.
Unable to find version '3.5.0.2' of package 'Antlr'.
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.  An error occurred while sending the request.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'api.nuget.org'
I receive similar messages for other packages like bootstrap, jQuery, and Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, all indicating that they cannot be resolved.
Dockerfile Snippet:
dockerfileCopy codeFROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY .sln .
COPY WebApp/.csproj ./WebApp/
COPY WebApp/*.config ./WebApp/
RUN nuget restore
Steps Taken:

Verified my internet connection.
Attempted to access https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json from my browser—it's reachable.
Considered using a local NuGet source but need guidance on how to configure this in the Docker build process.

What might be causing the remote name resolution failure during the Docker build?
How can I set up a local NuGet source in my Docker container to avoid this issue?

if docker (build) can't reach the internet its because its being blocked. either by a firewall, perhaps because docker is configured to use your lans cidr or some kind of other networking issue.
